# How to Get Ajax Strings to display for GET call

Tags: ajax, api, get

I'm trying to use an API to return data for 2 string variables: "_id" and "name". I'm connected correctly because I've tested the error feature by tweaking the API key and I get an error. I don't get that when I put in the correct API. However, what I do get is [Object object].

Here is the ajax code I am using (without the api keys):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit-button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: "myurl",
      headers: { "x-api-key": "myapikey" },
      data: $("#cdn :input").serialize(),
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data){
     $(".result").text(data);
      },
      error: function(d) {
        $(".result").html(d.responseText);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="cdn">
      <div> 
      <button id="submit-button">Submit</button>
    </div>
      <div class="result"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated. I need to be able to get the responses displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The variable "data" in your "success" function is actually a json object.

So you need to get the property in that object.

Let's say the response from the server has a property named "name"
you would have to do this:

```
 $(".result").text(data.name);
```